# log4j doesn't find appenders

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Always I try to use a formal and structurized log api is a nightmare (this explains why so many people just print to console)

I'm trying to use log4j in my project

to instantiate the logger I do:

```
   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Instagram.class.getPackage().getName());
```

when I want to register an event I do:

```
log.info("some information");
```

I've a `log4j.properties` file in the src folder like:

```
log4j.logger.com.tomatechines.instagramapi.api = INFO, CONSOLE, FILE, ERROR

log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE, ERROR

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern = yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.FILE.File = logs/log-
log4j.appender.FILE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.ERROR=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ERROR.DatePattern = yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.ERROR.File = logs/errorlog-
log4j.appender.ERROR.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ERROR.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.ERROR.Threshold=WARN

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n
```

but when the code runs the only thing printed to console or file is:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.tomatechines.instagramapi.api).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

why it doesn't find my file, I set 3 appenders and why can't it find just one

Comment: Is this a new project or an existing project? If this is a new project I would suggest using log4j2 as it has many enhancements over log4j1.x including better documentation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I can see that you are using SLF4J with log4j 1.2.x, because you are instantiating the logger with `LoggerFactory.getLogger`. If you want to use only log4j 1.2.x you should get the logger with `Logger.getLogger`. Making sure that you have imported the classes from `org.apache.log4j` package.

You must also make sure that you have put the `log4j.properties` file under the classpath. And in my opinion you should try first with a very simple configuration, to avoid configuration problems. Something like:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Probably your problem is about the location of `log4j.properties` file.

Comment: what is the difference between LoggerFactory.getLogger and Logger.getLogger

Comment: Look at imports: LoggerFactory is in the org.slf4j package and Logger.getLogger is in org.apache.log4j. Are different frameworks, you can use then together, but if you are new with log4j, I think that you should start using only log4j.

Comment: slf4j let me plug the implementation out of pain... i had a nightmare using apache log4j when i needed to put the code in android

Comment: I think that is not any problem about the use of slf4j... your problem is probabily because log4j.properties is not under the classpath or someone have overriden the default configuration procedure of log4j. Take a look at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit